# Single script to fully manage .net SQL membership provider data

Tags: asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, sqlmembershipprovider

3 Years ago I came across a really nice script. It was just an aspx and aspx.cs script, nothing more. It allowed me to see all the roles and users on site.

I could easily add/remove roles and add users to roles.

It used ajax for nice ui too.

Does anyone know where I can find this script?

I would like to use it again because setting it up was so simple. All I did was point it to the correct membershipProviderId and I was set.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the [ASP.Net Web Site Administration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0.aspx)?